# AWS - Cloudfront + S3 : how to change the S3 object key name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to generate an url signed by Cloudfront (to set expiration of the link) for S3 object.

My code is in Nodejs:

```
var cfsign = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');
var moment = require('moment');
var options = {
        keypairId: 'XXXXXXXX',
        privateKeyPath: './pk-XXXXXX.pem',
        expireTime: moment().add(60 * 30, 'seconds') //expired after 30 mins
    };
myUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl('https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/bucket/s3object.mp4', options);
```

Result: the signed url is generated and worked fine with expiration is 30 mins. ("https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/bucket/s3object.mp4?....")

My question: Is there any way to change the s3 object key (s3object.mp4) in the signed url?

Comment: *Is there any way to change the s3 object key?* For what purpose?

Comment: because the logic of my project can be extracted from object key, so I don't wanna user know it.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying... if my report is reports/departments/26.xlsx then I might be inclined to tweak the URL to get an unauthorized look at the report for department 25 or 27, etc... but you can take your signed URL and try changing it, modifying the path, leaving the signature the same.  That doesn't work, access is denied, and that's one purpose of a signed URL -- giving the user access to exactly one object, not others, or to a set of objects if the policy document contains a `*` in the URL.  Is that what you're talking about, or something more?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of changing the key name. If you want to have a different convention. You can use [AWS Lambda Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function to change the URL format.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on it.